# Reverse engineering a single checksum byte

Tags: hash, cryptanalysis

I am working to understand a system which saves a few bytes of data together with what appears to be a single checksum byte that provides a very naive guarantee that the data has not been tampered with. My current task is to understand how this checksum is being calculated.

I cannot currently post any specific data, but I do have reason to believe the checksum calculation is very easy to compute. I also know for a fact that it receives no more than 6 bytes of data as input, and quite possibly as little as one byte.

Given that I have a table of several samples of data bytes + checksums, is there a formal process to reverse engineer this checksum, or do I have to rely on simple logic deduction from the known facts that I have?

Comment: Huh? Why the downvote?

Comment: I'm not the downvoter, but I guess because at its current state the question is not really answerable.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about cryptography. It might be suitable for [reverseengineering.se], though more information would probably be required for a useful answer.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to see about the given pairs of plain text and checksum. Try to find two only marginal different plain texts with the same checksum. (Shouldn't be do difficult with only one byte (256 possibilities) per checksum.
Try a few one byte long plain texts and look for correlations of the checksum.
What's the checksum of 8 zero bits? And 8 one bits? What's the checksum of the byte value of 1?

You say the checksum only gets 6 bytes as input... Is this because the checksum doesn't change with a seventh byte or because the input is just truncated / never exceeds 6 bytes?

A good guess could be the [Cyclic redundancy check](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cyclic_redundancy_check) with 8 bits or with 32 bits truncated to 8 bits.

The most important thing is to know which algorithm was used. After that, the whole thing becomes much easier.

Comment: I have a few test cases where a single increment to a single significant data byte (i.e. from `a1` to `a2`) changed the checksum byte by 2 (i.e. from `54` to `56`). The checksum receives at most 6 bytes since those are the only relevant data bytes for this process, and as mentioned, it might possibly be just a single byte that is checked. So just for testing, what would an 8-bit CRC check on a single byte look like?

Comment: @YuvalAdam You can look at the definition of CRC through the link in my answer (i have corrected the link). Would it be possible to get some more pairs of plain text - checksum?

Comment: yes I'll try to clean the data and publish some of it.